# Opera house 10234 book 2 instruction 20 left hand side and then 22 has got me stumped. Can't figure out how these pieces fit. Please help

Tags: instructions

Opera house 10234 book 2 instruction 20 left hand side and then instruction 22 has got me stumped. I am not sure whether there is a space between the "high 2 and the blue 4. Please help

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed 1 stud between both parts.

The gray 2x1 is on the yellow 1x1 and 1 stud of the brown 6x1, than there is 1 free stud on the brown piece. The blue brick is on the remaining 4 studs of the 6x1